# Get data from discussions list in community site sorted by the count of Replies

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, community-site

I have tried both `CAML` query and `REST API` to retrieve data from the Discussions List in the community site but I am unable to accesss the `Replies` column.

How to access this column and sort data?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the list of replies

```
_api/lists/getByTitle('listname')/items?$filter=ContentType eq 'Message'
```

or

```
/_api/lists/getByTitle('listname')/items?$filter=FSObjType eq 0
```

To get the list of Discussions with the replies count:

```
/_api/lists/getByTitle('listname')/items?$select=ID,Title,Body,Folder/ItemCount &$expand=Folder/ItemCount &$filter=ContentType eq 'Discussion'
```